# Using the GridLayout in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to learn [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/). In the process, I thought I would create some common screens. The first being a Login screen. In that effort, I created the following xml.

**Login.xml**

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <GridLayout columns="*, *", rows="80, 80, 80, 80, auto">
    <Label text="Username" row="0" col="0" />
    <TextField row="1" col="0"  />

    <Label text="Password" row="2"  col="0" />
    <TextField row="3" col="0" />
  </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

When I run this app, all 4 controls (Label, TextField, Label, TextField) are sitting on top of one another halfway down the screen. I don't understand why. I'm just trying to use a basic [GridLayout](http://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/layouts/grid-layout/HOW-TO.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second line, you've a faulty comma between the columns and rows declarations. In XML, properties are separated with whitespace.

```
<GridLayout columns="*, *", rows="80, 80, 80, 80, auto">
```

should be

```
<GridLayout columns="*, *" rows="80, 80, 80, 80, auto">
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the extra comma there, you also could remove the columns property as you are setting all as col=0 it will be by default set as 0